# Setting up a homogenous linear ODE from its roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Set up a linear ODE of smallest possible order that has solutions $$y_1{(t)} = t
^a$$ and $$y_2{(t)} = e^{−t}
cos bt$$,

What i tried

For $y_{1}(t)$ One of the solutions is $t^{a}$ while the other solutions are $t^{a-1}$,$t^{a-2}$,$t^{a-3}$...$t$ and $1$ for a total of $t+1$ linearly independent
 solutions

While for $y_{2}(t)$ the other solution will be $$y_2{(t)} = e^{−t}
sin bt$$

Changing to complex number form, we have $$y_{2}(t)=-1+bi$$ and $$y_{2}(t)=-1-bi$$

Hence the equation becomes

$(r-(-1+bi))$$(r-(-1+-i))$ expanding it becomes $$r^2+2r+b^2$$ Im unsure about my workings though. Could anyone explain how to set up the ODE. Thanks

Comment: I think you should have that one product is $r^2+2r+b^2+1$

Comment: How did u get that, I couldnt get it. Could u please explain. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I multiply what you had. Well you have I think $(r-(-1+bi))(r-(-1-bi))$ instead of the thingy you wrote. I assume that was just a type-o. I'm going to use that $(r-(-1+bi))(r-(-1-bi))=r^2-r(-1-bi)-r(-1+bi)+(-1+bi)(-1-bi)=r^2+r+bi r+r-r bi +[1+bi-bi-b^2i^2]=r^2+2r+r(bi-bi)+1+(bi-bi)-b^2(-1)=r^2+2r+0+1+0+b^2=r^2+2r+b^2+1$ so for that one solution you have you can say you have the differential equation $y''+2y'+(b^2+1)y=0$ I would have to think about the other one a little more. So the other solution is $y=t^a$. I found the other differential equation by taking derivative of both sides. So we had $y'=at^{a-1}=\frac{at^a}{t}=\frac{ay}{t}$ which means we can write this as $ty'-ay=0$. And then solving the differential equation $(ty'-ay)(y''+2y'+(b^2+1)y)=0$ will yield the solutions you have.

Comment: Yup Thanks I got it. I just expand it normally.

Comment: One of the solutions are $t^{a}$ while the other solutions are $t^{a-1}$,$t^{a-2}$,$t^{a-3}$...$t$ and $1$ for a total of $t+1$ linearly independent solutions. The problem now is how do we expand those solutions  to get a linear ODE

Comment: Well $y'=at^{a-1}$ gives a solution $y=t^a$

Comment: Yup now we have to combine this solution with that of $y_{2}(t)$ the get the original ODE.

Comment: I'm sorry @ys wong I might be stuck at this part. I will continue to think until someone else chimes in.

Comment: I got it. We have $ty'-ay=0$ and $y''+2y'+(b^2+1)y=0$ multiply! :)

Comment: Erm i dont think thats the answer. It seems close but not quite.

Comment: Maybe it isn't the smallest possible order differential equation .

Comment: Based on my answer sheet, the right answer  should be $y^{a+3}+2y^{{a+2}}+(b^2+1)y^{a+1}=0$